# ServerSocket в веб-приложении

Tags: java, сокет, java-ee

Как можно в веб-приложение встроить ServerSocket на определенному порту?
Когда, как и где нужно его запускать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете создать самый обычный socket-сервер:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
```

Если вам просто нужна точка входа в веб-приложении, стартующая при старте приложения, то напишите класс, реализующий интерфейс [`javax.servlet.ServletContextListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) и в методе `contextInitialized()` вызывайте инициализацию вашего socket-сервера.

Действия, которые должны быть произведены при остановке web-приложения, выполняются в методе `contextDestroyed()`

```
public class SocketServerListener implements ServletContextListener {
    private static final int PORT = 3333;
    private ServerSocket server;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        server = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        // ...   
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        server.close();
    }
}
```

Если вы используете Servlet API старше, чем 3.0 - добавьте listener в `web.xml`

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>my.package.SocketServerListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Начиная с Servlet API 3.0, вам достаточно пометить ваш класс аннотацией [`@WebListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html):

```
@WebListener
public class SocketServerListener implements ServletContextListener {
//...
}
```

---

Comment: Если вы не против, я немного откорректирую вопрос и ответ, чтобы они лучше отражали суть нашего обсуждения.